# Getting id from selected listview item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a ListView containing this data template:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRitten" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gold" ItemsSource="{Binding ObcRitten}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="lvRitten_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Rit}">
            <Button x:Name="btnride" Height="100" Width="132" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Height="100" Width="132">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Aquamarine">
                            <Label Content="naam"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="AntiqueWhite">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label Content="{Binding id}" FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Naam}" FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding AantalPassagiers}" FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding TaxiNummer}" FontSize="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">

                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

but now I want to get the `id` that's in the first label in the 3rd grid when I click on a ListViewItem.

What is the easiest way to get the id?

Can I use binding to bind the id to a other label?
Or do I need to do something else?

ObcRitten is a public ObservableCollection and is filled with Rit
example of a Rit

```
Rit rit1 = new Rit
{
    id = 20,
    AantalPassagiers = 5,
    Naam = "Jan",
    TaxiNummer = 1
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all elements inside DataTemplate share the same DataContext, namely `Rit` item. To display `id` twice in different places you need to create two labels, and bind both to `id`

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
     <Label Content="{Binding id}" FontSize="10"/>
</Grid>
```

outside of ListView bind to ListView.SelectedItem:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.id, ElementName=lvRitten}" FontSize="10"/>
```

Comment: i know that but i need the id outside the list view, also there a more items in the list view

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the `SelectedItem` property to a `Rit` and access the `id` property:

```
Rit rit = lvRitten.SelectedItem as Rit;
if (rit != null)
    var id = rit.id;
```

You could also bind it directly to a `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.id, ElementName=lvRitten}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new property in your ViewModel:

```
public Rit SelectedRit {get; set;}
```

Then bind this property with ListView:

```
<ListView SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedRit}"..../>
```

Comment: I'm new to binding where do i put the property?

Comment: @Jeffrey in the same class, where is your ObservableCollection